# My change_square function will not recognize a negative input, any ideas why? (It doesn't decrement the value of shape, only increments)

Tags: python

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side

    def calculate_perimeter(self):
        return self.side * 4

    def change_square(self, new_side):

        if new_side < 0:
            self.side -= new_side

        if new_side > 0:
            self.side += new_side
            #return new_side

shape = Square(5)
print(shape.calculate_perimeter())

shape.change_square(-4)
print(shape.calculate_perimeter())
```

Comment: Next time, instead of keeping the entire description in the title, please put it in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subtract a negative it adds it. So you only need to add, not subtract. Take out the if statements and just have:

```
self.side += new_side
```

When you add a negative, it subtracts.